# Handling access privilege in liquibase with postgres

Tags: postgresql, liquibase

I am new to liquibase. I am using the [sql formatted changelogs](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/changelogs/sql-format.html?_ga=2.247478853.375258907.1660800010-1391885298.1660493357) 1 for postgres RDS. We run liquibase using `masteruser` in postgres and the application accesses the database using a different user in postgres, `appsuer`.

If I am creating a new table in database via liquibase. The `appuser` do not have the privilege to access the new table. So every time, I have to execute the below command as `masteruser` on the app DB after a new table is created.

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, REFERENCES, TRIGGER ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO appsuer;
```

Can someone let me know how to handle the `GRANT` also via liquibase SQL formatted changelogs or there are some other simpler and recommended ways? We only have two users in the database as mentioned here.

I executed the below command as `masteruser` on the app DB.

```
GRANT appuser to masteruser;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES
    FOR USER appuser
    IN SCHEMA public
    GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, REFERENCES, TRIGGER ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO appsuer ;
```

But then each time a new table is created via liquibase I have to execute the `GRANT` command once again inspite of `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGE` command being executed.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - I have updated the question. I have already tried it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create some changelog that will be executed every time with `runAlways` and put it at the end of the list of your changelogs/files so it will be executed every time as the latest one.

maybe something like this (I'm not familiar with formatted sql)

```sql
--changeset author:you id:someid runAlways:true dbms:postgresql
GRANT appuser to masteruser;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES
    FOR USER appuser
    IN SCHEMA public
    GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, REFERENCES, TRIGGER ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO appsuer ;
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to `runAlways`. Also can you let me know why you have preferred `runAlways` over `runOnChange`? In my case GRANT needs to be executed only when there is some change in the worst case.

Comment: `runOnChange` means you would need to change something in that `changeSet`. I expect that you don't need to change anything in script that assigns privileges to user.

Comment: Do you have any idea why I have to do ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGE everytime a table is created via liquibase? As per the postgres [doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html) seems it is needed to be done once and all newly created table will have those privilege.

Comment: Ok I have found my answer [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/186797/alter-default-privileges-permission-denied).